# Read single line from FTP server without downloading whole file using it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient

Tags: java, file, io, ftp

How can we read single line from FTP server without downloading whole file using `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.`

Now, I am downloading whole file and than reading first line of file, is there any way we can read first line of file without download file in local machine. It should use only it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j

@http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php

NOTE : It should use `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient` and not `apache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohit,

Use the **Socket dtConnection;**  ***dtConnection.getInputStream();***  of ftp4j.FTPClient you will get InputStream,  Using that InputStream you can read first line of.

you can find below Example hoe to read first line using InputStream

**BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String firstLine = null;**

**bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.dataTransferInputStream, "UTF-8"));
          firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine();**

Hope this solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own stream class that throws an exception after it has the first line written to it.

Edit: or it could call `abortCurrentDataTransfer()` after it received the first line.

Comment: Thanks @Sjoerd  for the response, however I am having few concerns,   1. I am not sure how to read the first line from FTP server using it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient. (if you have any example please share with me)  .  2. Also if you have any example of abortCurrentDataTransfer(),, please share with me.   Thanks for you help.

Comment: can i have sample code for this, we can read only single line of file from FTP remote server using ftp4j.

Comment: Hi @Sjoerd Could you please share some example to abortCurrentDataTrasfer() while downloading the file using ftp4j.